# SQL summing to 0 if no row found, while using a join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a lot of trouble with this query but I really feel like I shouldn't. I've converted my problem to a simpler one so it's easier to understand.

```
flowers_table
+---------------+-----------+
| flower_id     | name      |
+---------------+-----------+
| 1             | Tulips    |
| 2             | Rose      |
| 3             | Sun Flower|
| 4             | Orchids   |
+---------------+-----------+

transaction_table
+------------+------------------+
| trans_id   |  flower_id | sold|
+------------+------------------+
| 1          |    1       | 2   |
| 2          |    1       | 10  |
+------------+------------+-----+
```

Result:

```
+---------------+-----------+
| flower_id     | sold      |
+---------------+-----------+
| 1             | 12        |
| 2             | 0         |
| 3             | 0         |
| 4             | 0         |
+---------------+-----------+
```

This is what I came up with.

```
SELECT flower_id.flower_table, COALESCE(SUM(transaction_table.sold), 0) AS sold
FROM flowers_table, transaction_table
Where flowers_table.flower_id = transaction_table.flower_id 
GROUP by flower_id
```

Comment: Seems about right to me. Only `flower_id` 1 has sold items. Whats the question?

Comment: Surprisingly it won't produce the result, which is why I was scratching my head. If I recall, rows not in the transaction_table don't show up due to the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT flower_id.flower_table, COALESCE(SUM(transaction_table.sold), 0) AS sold
FROM flowers_table LEFT JOIN transaction_table on flowers_table.flower_id = transaction_table.flower_id 
GROUP by flowers_table.flower_id
```

Comment: Ahh, I initially tried this but failed. What I did was flip which tables were on both sides of "left join". Much love.